# Fragment not showing up with recycleView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a general question.
After dynamically defining a fragment that contains an EditText and a `RecyclerView`, by `onClicking()` a button we are supposed to see that fragment but it doesn't appear.
Only after I delete the RecyclerView the fragment shows up.

moreover its there any rules for defining a frame layout in `XML` file to the container of my fragment?
Thank You :)

Comment: If you could share the code it will be helpful.

Comment: Hey, I won't downvote your post because you are new and that would be rude xD but, would you please share some code it would be easier for us ^^

Comment: right I'm new here and in android developing :),  so which code will be helpful ?(Fragment class or recycleView adapter or Xml file or everything....)